# Set line number on chunks of file

Tags: vimscript, line-numbers

Following an example such as:

```
##1##
many text
and lines
##z##
##2##
more text
##z##
...etc
```

How could i make the line number display only on chunks of text, inside of the ##digit## and the ##z## string?
Something like this:

```
0 ##1##
1 many text
2 and lines
0 ##z##
0 ##2##
1 more text
0 ##z##
```

So that it only show line number for the in-between text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar problem so I have developed and posted a plugin (https://github.com/rickhowe/partialnumber.vim).

In your example,

```
:g/^##.##\n\ze[^#]/+1,/[^#]\zs\n##.##$/ SetPNU
```

would show numbers in sign column.

Comment: I searched for this for days on github and somehow missed this :D

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. From `:h 'number'` (emphasis mine):

> Print the line number in front of ***each line***

You can only enable `number` or `relativenumber` for the whole window.

See:

```
:help 'number'
:help 'relativenumber'
```

**Edit:**

In Vim, this isn't feasible because `'signcolumn'` has a max width of 2 characters. For some reason, even though Neovim supports larger sign columns, each individual sign text must still be 1 or 2 characters. If this were not the case, it would be possible in Neovim ([Relevant source code](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/src/nvim/sign.c#L789-L793)). This would have to be changed.

This might be easier done in Lua (I don't know, I've never written a Lua plugin for Nvim), but here is a solution in Vimscript. No guarantees about performance or "correctness" (it's kind of just thrown together), but it appears to work, let me know if I've missed some bug:

```
let g:custom_number_delimiter='##'
let s:sign_id=500 " script level variable of current sign ID

function! s:get_section_lines() abort
    " save cursor pos to restore
    let l:cursor_pos=[line('.'), col('.')]

    " Get line number by:
    " 1. :g/re/p for start of sections
    " 2. split output of :g/re/p into List
    " 3. isolate line numbers from output
    let l:section_start_lnums=s:isolate_lnums(split(execute('g/' . g:custom_number_delimiter . '.\+' . g:custom_number_delimiter . '/p#'), "\n"))

    " no matches
    if len(l:section_start_lnums) == 0
        return []
    endif

    " restore cursor pos (:g/re/p moves to last match, be nice and put it back)
    call cursor(cursor_pos)

    " build list of ranges in the format [[range_start_line, range_end_line], ...]
    let l:prev_lnum=-1
    let l:curr_lnum=-1
    let l:sections=[]
    for lnum in l:section_start_lnums
        let l:prev_lnum=l:curr_lnum
        let l:curr_lnum=lnum

        if l:prev_lnum != -1
            call add(l:sections, [l:prev_lnum, l:curr_lnum-1])
        endif
    endfor

    " logically, final section extends to end of file
    call add(l:sections, [l:curr_lnum, line('$')])

    return l:sections
endfunction

" gradually trim line until only the line number remains
function! s:isolate_lnums(section_lines) abort
    if a:section_lines[0] =~ "Pattern not found"
        return []
    endif

    let l:lnums=[]
    for section_line in a:section_lines
        " trim trailing characters
        let l:lnum = substitute(section_line, '^\s\+\d\+\zs.*', '', '')

        " trim excess whitespace
        let l:lnum = substitute(l:lnum, '\s', '', 'g')

        call add(l:lnums, str2nr(l:lnum))
    endfor

    return l:lnums
endfunction

" define more signs, if needed
" note: doesn't abort on error
function! s:define_signs(sections)
    let l:biggest_diff=-1
    for section in a:sections
        let l:curr_diff=section[1]-section[0]
        let l:biggest_diff=l:curr_diff > l:biggest_diff ? l:curr_diff : l:biggest_diff
    endfor

    for i in range(l:biggest_diff+1)
        " fail silently when lnum is >= 100 in Vim
        " In NeoVim use :h 'signcolumn' and :h 'number' accordingly
        exec 'silent! sign define Lnum' . i . ' texthl=LineNr text=' . i
    endfor
endfunction

" place signs in buffer
" note: doesn't abort on error
function! s:place_signs(sections)
    " clear all of our signs for current buffer
    exec 'sign unplace * group=CustomNumber buffer=' . bufnr()

    " no matches
    if len(a:sections) == 0
        return
    endif

    " define signs, if needed
    call s:define_signs(a:sections)

    for section in a:sections
        let l:custom_lnum=0
        for lnum in range(section[0], section[1])
            exec 'silent! sign place ' . s:sign_id . ' line=' . lnum . ' name=Lnum' . l:custom_lnum . ' group=CustomNumber buffer=' . bufnr()
            let l:custom_lnum+=1
            let s:sign_id+=1
        endfor
    endfor
endfunction

augroup CustomNumber
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter,BufNew,TextChanged,TextChangedI,TextChangedP * call s:place_signs(s:get_section_lines())
augroup END
```

And here is what that looks like in Vim:

[image: example picture]

See:

```
:h 'signcolumn'
:h :sign
:h :sign-define
:h :sign-place
:h :sign-unplace
```

Comment: added an edit to my example, do you think it is still impossible? (in vimscript)

Comment: You could *technically* use some of the things from `:h sign-commands` and/or `:h sign-function-details`, but in my opinion a sign column-based numbering system would be clunky and awkward. In addition to the mess that would be managing sign column numbering, you might also have to implement a system similar to `:h indentexpr`, in order to calculate how each line should be numbered. Again, doable, but not simple.

Comment: would love an example given it's doable :) (if you want i mean)

Comment: and i'm well aware on the "clunky and awkward" part, but that's only because i didn't specify in more detail the use for it, since it'll be offtopic (and the example succeed in illustrating the goal)

Comment: Is there a guarantee that your sections will always be < 100 lines? Sign text can only be two characters in width.

Comment: didn't knew this limitation :o. Well, there isn't no, planned the lines to be more than 100 lines at least.

Comment: btw, look like the 2 character wide limit isn't too much of a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17057230/12349101).

Comment: @NordineLotfi I've updated my answer with a first pass solution

Comment: Seems it throw [errors](https://pastebin.com/raw/z01PvDtx) on Vim 8.1.

Comment: Is it in a file named `numbers.vim`? That’s what that error is telling you.

Comment: No :). Tried opening different files, including my .vimrc. Same errors.

Comment: What is the vim version you're using? Maybe if i use the same i could check if it work better.

Comment: Wait, did you mean to put the code into it's own file, named `numbers.vim`? Sorry if i misunderstand.

Comment: I've edited my answer to allow you to put it as-is into your `vimrc`.